# Future for Web Proxy Auto-Discovery IETF Draft Specification?

Tags: proxy, specifications, wpad.dat

What future can we expect for the [Web Proxy Auto-Discovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol) Internet-Draft specification by the IETF?

I see a page on the MS MSDN website that describes MS current [WinHTTP AutoProxy Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384240(v=vs.85).aspx) that provides a link to a [document that expired in 2001](http://www.wrec.org/Drafts/draft-cooper-webi-wpad-00.txt) and the one on Wikipedia [link expired in 1999](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-wrec-wpad-01).

Has anyone heard of any replacement technology or should we continue to deploy WPAD at our various sites?  I'm not talking about transparent proxies either, I mean replacement method of distributing proxy information to all random client devices that connect to our network.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see it going away any time soon under Microsoft's umbrella - deprecating anything that businesses are using is something they avoid.

On the IETF draft, don't worry much about it; Microsoft's rarely interested in working through the open standards process for technologies that come from under their roof, but in this case it became a de-facto standard through wide deployment and at least some measure of implementation from other vendors.